# How do I mock the implementation of material-ui withStyles?

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs, material-ui

How do I mock the implementation of `withStyles` in `material-ui/core/styles.js`?

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

import TempComponent from './TempComponent'

jest.mock('@material-ui/core')

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const withStylesFake = styles =>
    component => (
      component
    )

  withStyles.mockImplementation(withStylesFake)

  const wrapper = shallow(<TempComponent />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const TempComponent = () => (
  <button>Click Me!</button>
)

export default withStyles({})(TempComponent)
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: _styles.withStyles.mockImplementation is not a function

  at Object.<anonymous>.it (src/TempComponent.snapshot.test.js:15:22)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

This would work:

```
// ./__mocks__/@material-ui/core/styles
export const withStyles = styles => (
  component => (
    component
  )
)
```

but this is not local to the test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I found around this was to export the component as follows. No mocks necessary.

Test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

import { TempComponent } from './TempComponent'

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TempComponent />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Implementation:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export const TempComponent = () => (
  <button>Click Me!</button>
)

export default withStyles({})(TempComponent)
```

Comment: the same way working for me with material UI 1 withStyle was working but later upgraded it to 4 then it starts breaking, by the above solution I am fixing unit test cases but is there any reason? I checked the adapter version or even tried deep: true with createshallow as very soon createShallow will be deprecated but still not working withstyle.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `TempComponent` import is evaluated before your test code, you'll need to mock withStyles earlier in the process. Calling mockImplementation occurs too late in the process.

There are two ways to do that: pass a factory into `jest.mock`, or use a manual mock. The manual mock is working for you, but you say you want something local to the test, so you'll want to use the factory parameter. Here's how.

Mock the `styles` import instead of the `core` import. Use the second arg to jest.mock, the "module factory parameter," to pass in a module factory function: a function that returns an object that replaces the `styles` import. For your purposes, that means the object needs to have a `withStyles` function:

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/styles', () => ({
  withStyles: styles => component => component
}));
```

No need to import `withStyles` into your test or call mockImplementation; you can delete those lines.

Comment: Hey, good catch. However, how to do that and mock the `theme` object that is passed as argument to `withStyles`?

Comment: @GuilhermeVasconcelos, I probably don't understand what you want to do, but if your goal is to test a component that is wrapped in `withStyles`, and not to test `withStyles` itself (which was written by someone else), then you don't need to mock the theme object. To test different values that would be set by the `withStyles` wrapper, set them as props on the component in the test. If that doesn't help, it's probably better to ask a new question.

Comment: actually, I'm testing a component that I named export to avoid its own withStyles. However, it internally uses another component that also has a withStyles `style = (theme) => ...theme.pallete` etc. So the code breaks since I'm setting up a theme (and don't want to).

Comment: Better to post a new question.

Comment: @GuilhermeVasconcelos I've been looking for this since this morning, I found a way to mock `makeStyles` and make it use the custom theme instead of the default one. But not the `withStyles` which I'm not really using, I stay in Hook practice. I just mock is, and BIND the function passed as arguments TO `bind.(null, theme)`, where I create the theme at manual Mocks global level with jest.

Comment: @GuilhermeVasconcelos I just found the PERFECT way to manual mock `makeStyles` solving all 4 main problems: 1- `undefined theme`, 2- Normal Test Coverage, 3- Advance Test Coverage when passing parameters inside `useStyles` and receiving them in `makeStyles` function property.

Comment: 4- `useStyles()` error when mocking `React.context` messes up with `makeStyles` function result that uses `React.context` internally.

Comment: this solution works well excepted for prop `classes` being undefined in the mounted components, and I struggle finding a way to mock this prop...

Answer (score -3):

This is a way I used to define component style with material UI.

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    ...theme.mixins.gutters(),
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    maxWidth: theme.spacing.unit * 120,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
});

function PaperSheet() {
    return (
        <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={1} />
    );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(PaperSheet);
```

Comment: The question is about mocking `withStyles` for testing. It doesn't look like your answer addresses tests or mocking.